# Faye and Ruby: have Rspec read Faye log or messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, eventmachine, faye

How can I get Rspec or even Ruby to read a Faye message? They come through in Faye's log alright, but I can't seem to connect to Faye through Rspec:

```
it 'gets Faye message' do
  EM.run do
    client = Faye::Client.new('http://localhost:9292/faye')
    sub = client.subscribe('/documents') do |message|
      puts message
    end

    sub.callback do |message|
      puts message
    end
  end
end
```

This just hangs. The messages come through in Faye's log. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've solved my own problem. I'll post my solution here in the event that it helps someone else.

```
it 'generates a document process and gets a push response from faye' do
  EM.run do
    client = Faye::Client.new('http://localhost:9292/faye')

    Thread.new { subject.perform(:generate, id) }

    client.subscribe "/documents/#{id}/notify" do |response|
      publication = client.publish("/documents/#{id}/notify", '0')
      publication.callback do
        if response != '0'
          expect(response).to eq(id.to_s)
          EM.stop
        else
          p "FAYE RESPONSE: #{response}" # diagnostic only
        end
      end

      publication.errback { |error| p "FAYE RESPONSE: #{error.inspect}" }
    end
  end
end
```

My end game was simply to get Rspec to get the Faye messages sent from the `subject.perform...` process. Mission accomplished. Not the neatest thing in the world, but who cares.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/eventmachine/eventmachine/EventMachine.run
(Read the NOTE block)

I'd say the EM.run call blocks (never returns and waits for connections) and that's why your test hangs.
Not really seeing what your test is trying to do though, so I can't give you a pointer on how to improve this.

Comment: The test here isn't finished by any means, the above was to illustrate how I'm trying to get Ruby to read the messages in the Faye `/documents` channel.

Comment: I can change the test if need be to make it clearer, but just _reading_ the channel is enough for me.

Comment: I suppose you could subscribe to given channel and put the results into an array. When you are done you can then assert on the contents of that array.

Comment: Think of Arrange, Act, Assert while writing your test, you are trying to arrange a given state, do something and then check an assumption about what should have happened.